# if bitcoin plunges to $0 will altcoins be affected?

Tags: exchange-rate

If the value of bitcoin where to drop significantly to amost no value would altcoins be affected ?

i guess they would because usually we convert to BTC before cashing out into fiat but wanted other opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for the reason you gave firstly (because most exchanges only have BTC/alt markets not alt/fiat markets), but also because Bitcoin is the first, most well known, and longest standing currency. If its value dropped to near 0, that would be a reflection of public loss of faith in cryptocurrencies in general, not just bitcoin, Bitcoin basically represents all cryptocurrencies to laypeople and its death would likely coincide with the death of all other currencies.

Comment: what do you think about something like DENT coin. where you can use DENT coin to buy mobile data. How would bitcoin dropping affect that ? i see it continuing if bitcoin plunges.  because i can still use a DENT coin to buy mobile data.  what do you think  @Bitcoin071474 and @MeshCollider?

Answer (score 1):

Yes all altcoins would be affected but does not mean they would all go to zero. You can alwaus convert to etherum and still sell it. Wont happen though. Maybe it will drop but most likely will contimue to bounce up and down.